# Magento 2 while upgrading an error of requires facebook/php-business-sdk but these conflict

Tags: magento2.4, composer, facebook, vendor, php8

We are using Magento 2

We are able to install Facebook Business SDK installation via composer but when we are trying to install facebook-for-magento2(https://marketplace.magento.com/facebook-facebook-for-magento2.html) then we are getting this error on composer -
this is composer.json of facebook/php-business-sdk

```
{
  "name": "facebook/php-business-sdk",
  "description": "PHP SDK for Facebook Business",
  "type": "library",
  "keywords": [
    "facebook",
    "ads",
    "business",
    "sdk",
    "instagram",
    "page"
  ],
  "homepage": "https://developers.facebook.com/",
  "require": {
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.5 || ^7.0"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~9",
    "symfony/finder": "~2.6",
    "mockery/mockery": "1.3.3"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "FacebookAds\\": "src/FacebookAds/"
    }
  }
}
```

Getting this error on console -

```
facebook/facebook-for-magento2 1.4.5 requires facebook/php-business-sdk 9.0.3 -> satisfiable by 
facebook/php-business-sdk[9.0.3] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

Screenshot-
[image]

Comment: Check composer version which you are using and check for composer.json file.
Add minimum-stability and prefer-stable to your composer.json

Comment: @Oscprofessionals I am using composer version 1.10.26 and php-businees-sdk version is 15.0

Answer (score 0):

The error shown is pretty clear, it has compatibility minimum stability version of 1.4.5.

Check prerequisites for Facebook SDK with your Magento version:

The minimum stability and compatibility version are:

- Open Source (CE): 2.3 (current), 2.4 (current)
- Commerce on-prem (EE): 2.3 (current), 2.4 (current)
- Commerce on Cloud (ECE): 2.3 (current), 2.4 (current)

**Extension SDK Version:**
facebook-business_extension-1.2.5.zip

If you could check:
composer require facebook/php-business-sdk

PHP SDK is the dependency of this module which is creating conflict with current version.

please check the installation guide:

https://marketplace.magento.com/media/catalog/product/facebook-facebook-for-magento2-1-4-4-ce/installation_guides.pdf

Check the Github Repo:
https://github.com/facebookincubator/facebook-for-magento2